# array of values from page-object elements

Tags: ruby, page-object-gem

is there a better way to get an array of the elements values than the following

```
    descriptions = []
     page.file_descriptions_elements.each do |row|
       descriptions.push(row.value)
     end
```

Comment: In terms of "better", were you just looking for an easier to read code or something else like perhaps more performant (eg maybe getting 100 fields is slow)?

Comment: @justinko yes thanks you. I was looking for something easier to read and your response helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Enumerable#map](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) to reduce the code:

```
page.file_descriptions_elements.map(&:value)
```